# After level 20 I can still take new feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-levels

For the Rogue, the description of the Ability Score Improvement (PHB, p.96) says:

> When you reach 4th level, and again at 8th, 10th, 12th, 16th, and 19th
>   level, you can increase one ability score of your choice by 2...

and the Feats description says (PHB, p165):

> At certain level, your class gives you Ability ScoreImprovement
>   feature. Using the optional feats rule, you can forgo taking that
>   feature to take a feat of your choice instead.

Using logic you have the oportunity to receive a feat each 4 levels. So if I up my character to level 24, 28, 32... I can still take new feats?

Comment: Do the answers to this question answer your question? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49434/are-characters-limited-to-20th-level-in-5e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 5e characters don't continue leveling past 20th but instead may receive Epic Boons. The DMG p. 231 suggests using epic boons as a form of character advancement for "...characters who have no more levels to gain...", suggesting one each major quest or 30k xp.

That said expanding 5e beyond 20th level is entierly workable. A good discussion about how to approach this has already been had in the question [are characters limited to 20th level in 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49434/are-characters-limited-to-20th-level-in-5e).

Comment: But that means that if I have two classes I won't be able to rise one of those two classes to 20th level?

Comment: @VojLmefDosMilNueve more than that it means if you have two classes neither of them will be able to rise to 20th level. You will only be able to get the sum of your classes levels to 20.