# Does taking levels in a UA prestige class count against the level limit of 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, prestige-class, unearthed-arcana

In Wizards of the Coasts article “[Prestige Classes and Rune Magic](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/prestige-classes-and-rune-magic)” states that it uses the normal D&D multiclassing rules. Comparing it to what I know of D&D 3.5e prestige classes consist usually of four levels. Does this mean that in 5e, a character can only have 16 levels in a base class and 4 in the prestige instead of 20 levels in a base class and 4 in the prestige?

Comment: This is tagged d&d 5e but you talk about 3.5 prestige classes in the body.  What's going on there?

Comment: The majority of 3.5E prestige classes are 5 or 10 levels...

Comment: Did you read the PHB and the DMG?

Comment: I apologize I only briefly went over prestige in 3.5 to compare it to what Unearthed Arcana release as I never played anything other than 5e

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question boils down to two ingredients: Do prestige classes work like normal multiclassing, and does D&D 5e still have a level limit of 20?

1. Do prestige classes work like normal multiclassing? **[Yes](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Rune_Magic_Prestige_Class.pdf)**:

   > **Mechanically**, a prestige class is a character class that requires the same training and focus as any other class. **You enter a prestige class by way of the normal multiclassing rules.**
2. Does D&D 5e still have a level limit of 20? **Yes.**

   [The prestige class rules offered](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Rune_Magic_Prestige_Class.pdf) in the playtest material in Unearthed Arcana do not include any change to the base game's level limit, [which is level 20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49434/are-characters-limited-to-20th-level-in-5e).

As a side note, the first prestige class we've seen ([the Rune Scribe](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Rune_Magic_Prestige_Class.pdf)) offers 5 levels to multiclass into, not 4. It bears repeating that experience with mechanically unrelated games can be misleading and should generally be ignored when looking at how D&D 5e works.